# JDBI query when using type annotations?

Tags: postgresql, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm writing a Dropwizard app that needs to connect to the database, and using [SQL objects](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_api_argument_binding/) to query the DB, per the [Dropwizard docs](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/jdbi.html#usage).

The issue I'm running into is when my query is using a type specifier (`::`) being confused for a binding variable. Something like

`SELECT
   (a,
    b,
    c)::user_type
FROM ...
WHERE id = :id`

The parser is reading `::user_type` as a parameter placeholder. When I've escaped them with `\`, it says the query is not returning any rows, but if I run the query through `psql`, it does, so I'm guessing it's not so simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just use the SQL-standard `CAST` syntax not the PostgreSQL extension `::` syntax.

```
CAST (c AS user_type)
```